# Java @inject null pointer

Tags: annotations, jax-rs, aop, inject

I'm trying to inject an object on my aspect class, but the object has a null pointer reference.

That's the code:

```
@Aspect
public aspect RestRequestsAspect {

  @Inject @LoggerAnnotation private Logger logger;

  @Before("execution(* com.living.commty.rest.endpoints.interfaces.*.* (..))")
  public void beforeCall () { 
      logger.info(" - INFO TEST BEFORE - ");    
  }

  @After("execution(* com.living.commty.rest.endpoints.interfaces.*.* (..))")
  public void afterCall () {
      logger.info(" - INFO TEST AFTER - ");
  }
}
```

.

```
public class LoggerProducer {  

  @Produces @LoggerAnnotation 
  public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {  
      return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
  }  
}
```

.

```
@Qualifier 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface LoggerAnnotation { }
```

The debugger enters on the @Before and @After methods but the logger object has a null pointer reference.

What i'm missing?

Thanks.